# Passing data from listview

Tags: android, listview

Good night, to pass data from one listview generated a database I do so by Intent and capturing the value:

`intent.putExtra("name", listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());`

To pick do with Bundle:

`Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String myData = bundle.getString("name");
nombre.setText(miData);`

The problem is that I receive is in the form of array:

`{value = first name}`

I tried various shape and not get capture only the string "first course" because it is what is shown in the listview, any suggestions? Thank you!

PD -> Sorry if my English is not good.

Comment: please explain what problem you are facing again, it was not clear. Post some code, that will help us understand

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply but I do not get what I want, when I pick up the data from the database and pick them up

`arrayList.add (createList ("value" name));`

With the index or value

But I have solved:

`int start = myData.indexOf("=");
int end = myData.indexOf("}", start + 1);
nombre.setText(myData.substring(start + 1, end));`

is not an elegant solution, but eventually get him in the EditText name.